cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0 response is given
For Magento 2.4 project i runned command Curl -IL Domain in terminal and
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age = 0 response is given .
I talked to support of cloudways but they are not able to find out where this comes from.
I added command -
Header append Cache-Control "must-validate, max-age=3600"
and
Header unset Cache-Control
Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=3600"
in header
in .htaccess but it not change.
I can't even understand where it came from.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
